# Addtional parameter of Huber regression

Tags: r, regression, machine-learning, robust

In Huber regression, there is a delta parameter in it's mathematical formula.

[image: Huber Formula]

Now, performing this regression in R can be done through the function `rlm` and with `psi=psi.huber`

In such a situation what is the value of Delta parameter used? Does delta have special formula?

Comment: The documentation for `rlm` shows the default value of $\delta$ is $1.345.$  For its justification, see p. 3 of [Fox & Weisberg, 2013](http://users.stat.umn.edu/~sandy/courses/8053/handouts/robust.pdf).